# Regex in java to derive first few characters of line in file and use that as filename

Tags: java, regex

I have a requirement of splitting 1 file into multiple files.
The file will be of type:
1 T table1 "a,b,c,d,e,f"
2 W table1 "a,b,c,d,e,f"
3 D table1 "a,b,c,d,e,f"
I want to split this file into 3 files with naming conventions as 
1_T_table1 , 2_W_table1 and 3_D_table1
I have already split-ted files into 3 files but with naive names.
I want to name them as above.
Can anyone help me with naming these files :)
Below is the code :

Note: text.txt is the file getting split

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.lang.Object ;
import java.util.regex.Matcher ;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String inputFile="C:\\path\\test.txt"; 
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(inputFile)));
         String line=null;
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
         int count=1;
        try {
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                Matcher match = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]+ [TWD]").matcher(line);
                while (match.find())
                {
                sb.append("split"+"\r\n ");

                }

                if(sb.length()!=0){
                sb.append(line+"\r\n ");

                }

            }

            int c = 0;
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("split");
            Matcher m = p.matcher( sb.toString() );
            while (m.find()) {
                                c++;
                            }
            //System.out.println(c); 
            int index = 0;
            for(int i=0;i<=c  ;i++)
            {

               if(sb.length() > 0 && sb.toString().contains("split")){          
                File file = new File("C:\\path\\DOC_ID_"+i+".txt");
                PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file, "UTF-8");
                index = sb.toString().indexOf("split",2);
                //System.out.println(index);
                if(index>0)
                {
                writer.println(sb.toString().substring(7,index));
                sb.delete(0, index);
                }
                else
                {
                writer.println(sb.toString().substring(7,sb.length()));
                sb.delete(0, sb.length());
                }
                writer.close();


            }
            }

           } catch (Exception ex) {
             ex.printStackTrace();
           }
           finally {
                  br.close();
                }
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks Piyush for editing.

Comment: i am not getting you, but do you want something like **[this](https://regex101.com/r/wG7jA8/1)**?

Comment: that's exactly what I want .thanks

Comment: added the code..modify it as per your need..and do **[accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)** the answer

Comment: Thanks rock this is just what i needed . Extremely brilliant...Just 1 more issue , If my line starts with something like 
1 T table1-abc "a,b,c,d,e,f"
I need filename as " 1_T_table1-abc"
The regex you provided is fetching 1_T_table1

Comment: see the updated answer

Comment: Fantastic.. Thanks for the support rock321987

Comment: One more problem ,if my file has lines that does not start with

Comment: what do you want then?

Comment: One more problem ,if my file has lines that is not of format (1 T table) but some random thing like (abcdfg) , I want to skip that line

Comment: those case will be handled automatically.. **[check](https://regex101.com/r/wG7jA8/4)**

Comment: @A.Pathan: piyush's edit was destructive. Please do not accept such edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Till I understood, you need this regex

```
(\d+)\s+([TWD])\s+([\w-]+).*
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wG7jA8/2)**

*Java Code*

```
System.out.println(ln.replaceFirst("(\\d+)\\s+([TWD])\\s+([\\w-]+).*", "$1_$2_$3"));
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/7wUMaY)**